# Mysql import multiple CSV and SQL from a folder

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

First of all, my initial intention is simply want to rename/copy a database. But the thrist of knowledge is extending a little further.

I knew about `mysqldump db | mysql db`. I also knew about `LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE` to import a single CSV.

Mysql has a nice way to dump a DB as CSV into a single folder

`mysqldump -T/some/folder db`

Now that folder will contain both SQL and TXT files for each table (`table1.sql, table1.txt, ...`)

Why I'm choosing this method is because I have a database with 4Gb size, and using the traditionnal import is painfully slow. I heard that using CSV import might give a better performance.

Questions :

1. Is there any *official way* to do the reverse operation, which read from a folder that contains both SQL and TXT files?
2. Does exporting like this then import ensure an exact copy of the original DB? (indexes, primaries, uniques, views, etc...)

**EDIT:**

So I did some research.

- Not the best way but it's from official doc to do the reverse operation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reloading-delimited-text-dumps.html (O.Jones'answer)
- If we loop over the folder and import files one by one order alphabetically, we'll eventually run into InnoDB key constraints problem. Disable key check seems not solving the problem.

Quite a MYTH but `mysqldump` with `--opt` then import SQL seems import faster than CSV due to many optimizations! The command used is `mysqlimport` and not `LOAD DATA INFILE` (I will try later to see if there is any difference)

Comment: I never do this. usually I let another database be the slave and run a master / slave thing where the second database just learns from the master. in this way my second database can recover the first one very quick if the first one has a crash.

Comment: 1. Depends on what you mean by "official" - sanctioned by whom? One could write a batch file that outputs the required 'load local data..' statements based on the csv files found in the folder. Local data files are the fastest way to load bulk data.
2.You will only get an exact copy of the original DB if your mysql configuration exactly matches the source, as mySQL makes up its own mind about indexes for primary keys etc.

Comment: @MaxMuster Great! But not my need atm. I have a large (temporary) DB which is built with a script. Then if the build is successful, the temporary DB will starts to replace the official DB which is located in the same server.

Comment: @PeterBrand Official if possible from `mysql`. I wonder why they didn't develop smt to do the reverse operation. I'm afraid that loading the SQL first will slow down the insert process because `DISABLE KEYS` (which disable keys verification) is not present in the CSV file like the real SQL.

Comment: Did you look at this?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reloading-delimited-text-dumps.html  You need to run it table by table.

Comment: @O.Jones Nice for pointing out the official doc! So I still need to loop for each file I guess

Comment: Not sure why you'd like to go this way (using temporary files per table). I'd choose dump + load everything with data OR dump + load schema only and then a set of INSERT INTO .... SELECT.

Comment: @fifonik Not temporary file per table, it's CSV and a matter of import/export performance.

Comment: Is not CVS a file? I do not think getting all data from table into CVS file and loading it into another table would be fasted than insert ... select. But I have not tested, actually. So it is guessing only :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but there's a small trick you can do with bash.

cd to the folder where the files are and:

```
for x in $(ls *.txt); do mysqlimport -u YOURUSER -pYOURPASS --local database_to_import_into  $x;done
```

this will do the trick.